# remove previously added canvas text with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fabricjs

on change event of text-Area i want to change the text which is already drawn on canvas. following code i have written , using if/else condition i am removing text which was added earlier .remove doesn't works here perfectly . after text change if i drag text somewhere then text is changed to first one which is already removed what would be problem ?

```
$('#filedset').delegate(' textarea', 'change ', function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design_text');
    if (x == 0) {
        alert('if called');

        var message = $(this).val();

        console.log('text area change' + message);
        var text = new fabric.Text(message, {
            left: 150,
            top: 60
        });
        canvas.remove(text1);
        canvas.add(text);
        x = 1;
    } else {
        alert('else called');

        var message = $(this).val();

        console.log('text area change' + message);
        var text1 = new fabric.Text(message, {
            left: 150,
            top: 60
        });
        canvas.remove(text);
        canvas.add(text1);
        x = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Actual you creating a new fabric.Canvas instance everytime you change the text. Is this correct?
Maybe text.setText('jkasjdalksj'); is what your looking for?!

Comment: @Kienz yes i want to set text value ?? can i use set text method here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. I created small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/BTh6A/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design_text');

$('#filedset').on(' textarea', 'change ', function(e) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.item(0),
      text = e.target.value;

  if (!obj || obj.type !== 'text') return;

  obj.setText(text);

  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');   WHAT DOES WINDOW._CANVAS MEANS??

Comment: I use this to have access (developer console) to canvas object in jsfiddle. Otherwise you don't need that.

Comment: i have updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BTh6A/3/ to increase font_size with the same set method ... it is not working ?

Comment: Now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/BTh6A/7/. You can use obj.setFontSize(60) or obj.set('fontSize', 60) or obj.set({fontSize: 60});